# Move plot and legend in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to make a pie chart in matplotlib that look like this:

[image: there]

(differences in colors and borders aren't a big deal.)

I'm not exactly sure how to make this happen using matplotlib.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g_title = "Big fat redacted title (Income Distribution)"
g_data_list = [['FIN.RES 47% - $41,888.08', 47], ['VSC 40% - $36,019.00', 40], ['AFTERMARKET 6% - $5,570.00', 6], ['GAP 7% - $6,528.00', 7]]

labels = []
sizes = []
for entry in g_data_list:
    labels.append(entry[0])
    sizes.append(entry[1])

patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, startangle=90)
plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="center right", fontsize=6)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title("{}".format(g_title), fontsize=14)
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=100)
```

That gives

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure of what do you like, but one option is to use `loc="best"`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g_title = "Big fat redacted title (Income Distribution)"
g_data_list = [['FIN.RES 47% - $41,888.08', 47],
               ['VSC 40% - $36,019.00', 40],
               ['AFTERMARKET 6% - $5,570.00', 6],
               ['GAP 7% - $6,528.00', 7]]

labels = []
sizes = []
for entry in g_data_list:
    labels.append(entry[0])
    sizes.append(entry[1])

patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, startangle=90)
plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best", fontsize=6)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title(g_title, fontsize=14)
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=300)
```

That gives

[image]

Another option is to specify the size of your plot and fix the legend to a location

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g_title = "Big fat redacted title (Income Distribution)"
g_data_list = [['FIN.RES 47% - $41,888.08', 47],
               ['VSC 40% - $36,019.00', 40],
               ['AFTERMARKET 6% - $5,570.00', 6],
               ['GAP 7% - $6,528.00', 7]]

labels = []
sizes = []
for entry in g_data_list:
    labels.append(entry[0])
    sizes.append(entry[1])

ax = plt.subplot(111)
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.7, box.height])
patches, texts = ax.pie(sizes, startangle=90)
ax.legend(patches, labels, loc='center left',
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=8)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.suptitle(g_title, fontsize=14)
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=300)
```

That results in

[image]

Comment: Are you using IPython?

Comment: Just running it in pycharm .  Yours looks right but now the dimensions are massive - 2,400x1,800.  I need 300 x 575.

Comment: I have not used PyCharm before, it probably defines the size of the figure automatically. Run it in plain Python. If you need an image with less resolution, just change the parameter ``dpi`` from ``dpi=300`` to ``dpi=100``.